# Typescript thinks an object property is still number | undefined after assigning value

Tags: node.js, typescript

I feel like I'm missing something here.

I have a pretty basic Typescript interface with a few optional properties.

Then I have a function where I want one of the optional properties to become required using the `RequireField` type (defined below).

So I created a Person object, assigned the age after creating the object, and now Typescript is mad and thinks the property could still be undefined despite assigning it.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
  school?: string;
}

type RequireField<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, K>>

const myObj: Person = { name: 'test' };

myObj.age = 25;

calculateAge(myObj); // Intellisense error

function calculateAge(obj: RequireField<Person, 'age'>): void {
  console.log(obj)
}
```

Intellisense error:

```
Argument of type 'Person' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequireField<Person, "age">'.
  Type 'Person' is not assignable to type 'Required<Pick<Person, "age">>'.
    Types of property 'age' are incompatible.
      Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

The reason I'm confused is because it works when doing practically the same thing using `string | undefined`

```
let myString: string | undefined;

myString = 'test';

stringFunc(myString); // No intellisense errors

function stringFunc(str: string): void {
  console.log(str);
}
```

Why does typescript think `myObj.age` is `number | undefined` after assignment when `myString` is seen as just a string after assignment?

FWIW, I'm on TS 4.4.4

[image: Intellisense error message reference]

Comment: In theory Typescript could guess the correct, more specific type, but it doesn't. Typescript doesn't infer everything and it gets better with every version. Does answering the question 'why' help with your issue, because the answer is likely: "Because the developers have not built this yet"

Comment: @Evert This isn't really even a TS limitation. This is TS working as intended and it is **by design**, because `myObj` has type `Person`, and the property `age` in `Person` is optional, you should not be able to pass `myObj` to `calculateAge`, because the type of `myObj` is `Person`, and `Person` is not assignable to type `RequireField<Person, "age">`. Yes I suppose this *could* be a limitation and it *could* be fixed but that's just my take.

Comment: @vera sure but in theory it could _narrow_ the type which is exactly what happens with a type assertion. It's still a `Person`, but it's _also_ a `{age: number}`. It's certainly possible and I don't think it's out of the question that one day this will just work. But generally I agree, today it's by design and not a bug.

Comment: @Evert @vera. Thanks for the quick replies. Yeah, I guess I just assumed it would be able to infer that `myObj` now meets the requirements for `RequireField<Person, 'age'>`. Kind of a bummer. Even with a type check on `myObj.age` it still doesn't see it, so I'm guessing you're right that it was a design decision.

Comment: See [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) (someone should write up an answer, I think?)

Comment: I'll leave it up to one of you guys to write the answer since you guys pointed me in the right direction. If no one does after a while, I'll answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

There's a discussion in the comment section and we concluded that this is functioning by design for TS.

TS basically just see's `Person !== RequireField<Person, 'age'>` and is not able to infer an object's individual properties to know that it meets the requirements for other types.

### The Workaround

TS can't infer that `myObj` is a `{ name: string, age: number }`, but referencing the properties directly, TS knows `myObj.age` is a number after assignment.

So creating a new object with `{ name: myObj.name, age: myObj.age }` works.

Note: the spread operator doesn't work `{ ...myObj }` for the same reason above.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
  school?: string;
}

type RequireField<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, K>>

const myObj: Person = { name: 'test' };

myObj.age = 25;

calculateAge({ name: myObj.name, age: myObj.age }); // Workaround

calculateAge({ ...myObj }); // Doesn't work

function calculateAge(obj: RequireField<Person, 'age'>): void {
  console.log(obj)
}
```

Thanks for the discussion comments. Also, thanks to jcalz for the link https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384